# Show that this initial-value problem has a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to show that the following initial-value problem

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = - x + tx^{1/2}; \quad x(2) = 2$$

has a unique solution on $I = [2,3]$.

By letting $f(t,x) = - x + tx^{1/2}$ and $(t_0 , x_0) = (2,2)$ ,

I consider the rectangle $R$:

$$\{ (t,x) : |t-t_0| \le \alpha , |x-x_0| \le \beta \}$$

which is

$$\{ (t,x) : |t-2| \le \alpha , |x-2| \le \beta \}$$

The idea is that if all *t* lying in the range $|t-t_0| \le \min \{ \alpha , {\beta\over M} \}$ where $|f(t,x)| \le M$ , then this problem has a unique solution.

But I found difficulties in finding $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $M$ because of two variables and also *x* could not be negative, could any one helps? Thanks.